# Pandas: group and sum dataframe while adding min and max year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'], 'YEAR': [2000,2001,2002,2007,2008,2009,2015,2016,2017],
                  'ITEM-A': [100,200,300,700,800,900,1100,1200,1300], 'ITEM-B':[4000,5000,6000,3000,3500,4000,500,600,800]})
```

[image: Initial dataframe]

I want to group by the ID and sum ITEM-A and ITEM-B, but I also want to add 2 columns to include the min and max year (respectively) for each group. My ultimate goal is to end up with a dataframe that looks something like this:

[image: Final dataframe example]

What is the best way to accomplish this? My initial thought is to add the two new columns and populate each row with the min and max which should look something like this:

[image: Min-max example]

Then I could use a groupby/sum function to get the totals and drop the YEAR column.

I tried this code to add the columns but all I got were NaN values:

```
df['MIN-YR'] = df.groupby('ID')['YEAR'].min()
df['MAX-YR'] = df.groupby('ID')['YEAR'].max()
```

[image: NaN screenshot]

Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Am I on the right track? If so, what is causing the NaN values in the MIN-YR and MAX-YR columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `agg` and specify what function(s) to use for the aggregate per column:

```
(
 df
    .groupby("ID")
    .agg({"YEAR": ["min", "max"], "ITEM-A": "sum", "ITEM-B": "sum"})
)
```

This will generate the following table:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michael. That seems like a simpler process. I did figure out that using .transform(min) (or max) worked as well, but your solution takes out some steps.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this, using [Named Aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation), without multiindex column headers nor renaming:

```
df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg(**{'ITEM-A':('ITEM-A','sum'),
                                        'ITEM-B':('ITEM-B','sum'),
                                        'MIN-YR':('YEAR', 'min'),
                                        'MAX-YR':('YEAR','max')})
```

Output:

```
  ID  ITEM-A  ITEM-B  MIN-YR  MAX-YR
0  A     600   15000    2000    2002
1  B    2400   10500    2007    2009
2  C    3600    1900    2015    2017
```

Comment: Scott, your answer is very similar to Michael's. I like the way you structured yours, though. :)

Comment: @Heather Just an option.  Happy coding!  Be safe and stay healthy.